# How do you include a variable in a continuous sequence of characters

Tags: unix, csh

In csh, I have a variable called `$var` and I want to include it in a csh script as follows

```
#!/bin/csh

set var="directory"
sed 's/DIRECTORY_PATH/$var1234/' > output.txt
```

I want the sed statement to evaluate to `'s/DIRECTORY_PATH/directory1234'`, but instead it just tries to a lookup a variable called var1234.  What's the right way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use double quotes to have the var expanded in the `sed` command:

```
set var="directory"
sed "s/DIRECTORY_PATH/${var}1234/" > output.txt
    ^                            ^
```

Note the usage of braces in `${var}1234`: it makes bash understand the variable is `$var` and `1234` is text, so you can refer to the variable name concatenated with some string.

#### Example

```
$ var="me"
$ new_var="you"

$ echo "hello me" | sed 's/$var/$new_var/g' # <-- single quotes
hello me                                    # <-- no substitution

$ echo "hello me" | sed "s/$var/$new_var/g" # <-- double quotes
hello you                                   # <-- substitution!
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but it doesn't fully address the question. Suppose I wanted to replace `$var` with `$new_var` concatenated with 1234.  I couldn't say `sed 's/$var/$new_var1234/g` because it would just lookup a variable called `$new_var1234` which obviously doesn't work.  Do you know how I would do this?

Comment: Yes, use brackets braces --> `sed 's/$var/${new_var}1234/g`. This way, you are telling bash that the var name is just `new_var` and `1234` is just another thing.